# Uploading Image using Polymer and Node Js

Tags: node.js, polymer

Currently we are using Polymer for frontend.  In polymer we have element “vaadin-upload”.

**Issue**: We are not able to fire/trace node js code.  When we try to upload image then it throws POST 404 not found error.

Please check below code of Polymer and NodeJS.

**Polymer**:

```
<vaadin-upload target="http://localhost:5000/upload" method="POST" timeout="300000" headers="{'X-Custom-Header': 'value'}"></vaadin-upload>
```

**Node Js**:

```
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/upload',
    config: {
          payload:{
                maxBytes:209715200,
                output:'stream',
                parse: false
          }, 
          handler: function (request, reply) {
            var data = request.payload;
            if (data.file) {
                var name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                var path = __dirname + "/upload/" + name;
                var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

                file.on('error', function (err) { 
                    console.error(err) 
                });

                data.file.pipe(file);

                data.file.on('end', function (err) { 
                    var ret = {
                        filename: data.file.hapi.filename,
                        headers: data.file.hapi.headers
                    }
                    reply(JSON.stringify(ret));
                })
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [hapijs tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials) it looks like you need to define the port after you create the server instance.

```
server.connection({ port: 5000 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hapi will save the file to the directory for you so you don't have to handle it.

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    port: 5000
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
});

const PATH_TO_UPLOADED_FILES = '...';

server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/upload',
    config: {
        payload: {
            output: 'file',
            uploads: PATH_TO_UPLOADED_FILES,
            parse: true,
            maxBytes: 209715200
        },
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            // file path is at: request.payload.file.path
            reply('thanks');
        }
    }
});
```